# Magento Dashboard generates an SQL Error

Tags: magento

I'm having problems with the Dashboard in the admin section, not showing me any data.. I'm getting this error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

I'm having no clue as to what started the issue, here's the tracing:

```
0 /var/www/store/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/store/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/store/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/store/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /var/www/store/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /var/www/store/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /var/www/store/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(687): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(520): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /var/www/store/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(521): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /var/www/store/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(268): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/local/Ezapps/Zoom/Model/Mysql4/Page/Collection.php(28): Varien_Data_Collection->getFirstItem()
#11 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/local/Ezapps/Zoom/Block/Adminhtml/Dashboard/Tab/Zoom.php(38): Ezapps_Zoom_Model_Mysql4_Page_Collection->getStats()
#12 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Abstract.php(77): Ezapps_Zoom_Block_Adminhtml_Dashboard_Tab_Zoom->_prepareData()
#13 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Abstract->_prepareLayout()
#14 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(430): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#15 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/local/Ezapps/Tools/Block/Adminhtml/Dashboard/Diagrams.php(42): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('ezzoom/adminhtm...')
#16 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Ezapps_Tools_Block_Adminhtml_Dashboard_Diagrams->_prepareLayout()
#17 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(430): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#18 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard.php(66): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...')
#19 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard->_prepareLayout()
#20 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(430): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#21 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(446): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#22 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(238): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#23 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(204): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#24 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#25 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(345): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#26 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(270): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#27 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(263): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#28 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(40): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#29 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#30 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#31 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#32 /var/www/store/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(348): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#33 /var/www/store/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#34 /var/www/store/public_html/index.php(82): Mage::run('', 'store')
#35 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the stack trace the problem is caused by a custom module from Ezapps...

Try disabling the module (app/etc/modules/Ezapps_*.xml - set active to false) and check what other things need to be done in order to disable the module...

Within that module's code, there is a problem when forming the sql query...